# How to write @Override annotation

Tags: java, coding-style, annotations

I'm just curious, how i should write @Override annotation cause what i can see there are two ways. First:

```
class Lisa extends Homer {
  @Override void doh(Milhouse m) {
    System.out.println("doh(Milhouse)");
  }
}
```

source: Bruce Eckel, Thinking in Java, 4th edition.

Second way:

```
@Override
public LittleFish next() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
}
```

source: Eclipse methods auto-generator and i saw this in some other places.

I like to keep my code clean and consistent with Java rules so I'm really intereseting in this topic. Sorry for dumb question, but i couldn't find answer in Google and even here.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why

Comment: A matter of taste. Even the oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) shows both the styles. I prefer the second, but just pick one and stick with it.

Comment: I'd say http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464464/code-style-with-annotations is a closer duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle Java "Predefined Annotation Types"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html)

```
   // mark method as a superclass method
   // that has been overridden
   @Override 
   int overriddenMethod() { }
```

But in any case it's primarily opinion-based question

**EDIT**:

Also, it is a good style when you have more then one annotation on the method, e.g.:

```
   @Type
   @Column(name = "ID")
   @Override       
   int overriddenMethod() { }
```

looks better then

```
   @Type
   @Column(name = "ID")
   @Override int overriddenMethod() { }
```

or

```
   @Type @Column(name = "ID") @Override int overriddenMethod() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the `@Override` annotation the line before the method is  definitely much more readable. There's no functional difference between them as far as I am aware, but having all everything in one line lowers readability. You could write all your code in one line technically, but it's not very pretty.

[Oracles own Java-Annotations-tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html) indicates this is the proper way as well. You might also want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) from stack overflow where they talk a bit more about the override, albeit in a more general sense.

So this would be the proper way to do it :)

```
@Override
private int doStuff() {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
void mySuperMethod() { ... }
```

is how it is done in [**javadocs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    String display()
    { 
      // your code here
    }
```

This style strictly follows the java naming convention. You can try this.